# context undefined in Navigator.push

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a custom AppBar that I can use across multiple pages. `customappbar.dart`

```
class CustomAppBar extends AppBar {
  CustomAppBar({Key key, Widget title})
      : super(
          key: key,
          title: title,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context, //UNDEFINED
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NewPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
}
```

Here's an example of where it's going to go. `newpage.dart`

```
class _ NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CashOnHandAppBar(
        title: Text('New Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

context is getting of undefined. is the build method missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending AppBar class it will not work for custom appbar you have to extend StatelessWidget and implement PreferredSizeWidget class for custom appbar 
Here is the working example of custom appbar :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String _title;
  final bool centerTitle;

  SimpleAppBar(this._title, {this.centerTitle = false, Key key})
      : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(56.0),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(_title),
      centerTitle: centerTitle,
    );
  }
}
```

And instead of adding function directly into custom appbar pass function reference to the class constructor 
Need to pass below function add reference :-

```
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context, //UNDEFINED
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => NewPage(),
              ),
```